# VueJS component do not show correct data

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I'm new on Vue.js and I'm trying to update a template (article.vue) repeating a component to show all the data.

During my test, I'm using fake data books.

The file artile.vue is:

```
  <template>
   <div>
   <article-comp v-for="{book, index } in books" :key="index" :title="book.title"></article-comp>
</div>
 </template>

 <script>
  import Article from './../components/ArticleComponent'

export default {
    data: function () {
        return {
            books: [{
                userId: 1,
                id: 2,
                title: "delectus aut autem",
                completed: false
            }, {
                userId: 2,
                id: 1,
                title: "delectus aut autem",
                completed: false
            }, {
                userId: 3,
                id: 3,
                title: "delectus aut autem",
                completed: false
            }]
        }
    },
    components: {
        'article-comp': Article
    }
}

</script>
```

The file ArticleComponent has the line

```
 <a class="" href="/event/title/1">{{ title }}</a>
```

The render shows 3 links (correct) but the title is missing (empty)

What I'm doing wrong in:

```
    <article-comp v-for="{book, index } in books" :key="index" :title="book.title"></article-comp>
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to tell to ArticleComponent component that title is a prop (data is arriving from parent/outside).

```
export default {
 props: ['title']
}
```

Comment: Thanks. But I still have some issue. In v-for I have another error in "book.title": Error in render: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'title' of undefined"

Comment: @Uncoke oh i see now the error v-for must have parenthesis v-for="(book, index) in books"

Answer (score 0):

just try this

```
<template>
  <div v-if="books">
   <article-comp v-for="(book, index) in books" :key="index" :title="book.title"/> 
  </div>
</template>
```

the problem maybe is you component are not ready yet, so you need always with v-for directive use v-if to avoid this issues at rendering time

Comment: Vue is a reactive framework, When the data is available at a later time(fetched from an api or something) it would re-render. I guess v-if wouldnt be required.

Comment: There is issues if you are going to loop an array and you have this arrray with null

Comment: If you want to set array initial value till you get data from somewhere use an empty array literal [], instead of null(assuming that is what's happening).